# How to create a date range from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, date

I have a JSON file containing the values of a particular value at various points of time. Currently, it's messy and contains *a lot* of duplicates. I'd like to clean it up by organizing the duplicates into a date range.

The JSON file is structured as follows:

```
[
    {
        "value": ".298",
        "time": "21 May 2015 1:18:06 AM"
    },
    [...]
    {
        "value": ".298",
        "time": "21 May 2015 12:15:07 PM"
    },
    {
        "value": ".046",
        "time": "21 May 2015 12:20:08 PM"
    },
    [...]
    {
        "value": ".046",
        "time": "21 May 2015 12:30:15 PM"
    },
    {
        "value": ".004",
        "time": "22 May 2015 8:55:06 PM"
    },
    [...]
    {
        "value": ".004",
        "time": "22 May 2015 9:45:06 PM"
    }    
]
```

And I'd like the output:

```
21/05 01:19:06 AM to 21/05 12:15:07 PM, value: .298
21/05 12:25:08 PM to 21/05 12:30:15 PM, value: .046
22/05 09:40:06 PM to 22/05 09:45:06 PM, value: .004
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
foreach ($json as $sub) {
    if (isset($value)) {
        if ($value == $sub['value'] || $value == NULL) {
            $range[$i][] = [strtotime($sub['time']), $sub['value']];
        }
        else {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $value = $sub['value'];
}

foreach ($range as $daterange) {
    $begin = $daterange[0][0];
    $end = $daterange[count($daterange)-1][0];
    printf('%s to %s, value: %s', 
        date('d/m h:i:s A', $begin), 
        date('d/m h:i:s A', $end), 
        $daterange[0][1]
    );
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

The code I posted works for the most part, but when dealing with large arrays that includes null values, it seems to have issues. As in the duplicates are still there.

How can I fix it? I'm sure this hacky approach can be improved a lot more using DateTime class; I hope someone can show me how it's done.

Comment: Can you show an example of how the null values you mention show up?

Comment: *And I'd like the output:

21/05 01:19:06 AM to 21/05 12:15:07 PM, value: .298* Where do you take that time?

Comment: @splash58: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: in json  for .298   there are 2 times  "21 May 2015 1:18:06 AM" and "21 May 2015 12:15:07 PM". In  output 21/05 01:19:06 AM to 21/05 12:15:07

Answer (score 0):

I don't format the output. I think you can yourself

```
$array = json_decode($str);

$starttime = $endtime  = $array[0]->time; 
$value = $array[0]->value;

foreach ($array as $item) 
    if ($item->value == $value) $endtime = $item->time;
    else { 
        echo "$starttime to $endtime, value: $value\n";  
        $starttime = $endtime  = $item->time; 
        $value = $item->value;
    }
    echo "$starttime to $endtime, value: $value\n";
```

With data in question output:

```
21 May 2015 1:18:06 AM to 21 May 2015 12:15:07 PM, value: .298
21 May 2015 12:20:08 PM to 21 May 2015 12:30:15 PM, value: .046
22 May 2015 8:55:06 PM to 22 May 2015 9:45:06 PM, value: .004
```