# What's a clean way to get a value from a website periodically and organize it based on time?

Tags: php, date, cron, organization

I'm trying to get the value of a particular item from an API. The API returns the value in JSON format like `{ "value" : 32.22 }`. I need to track the value continuously using a cronjob that calls every 5 minutes.

Thee value only changes 4 or 5 times a day, so there would be a lot of duplicates. If I were to store all the values (along with the time at which it was obtained) into a text file, it would be 288 values for just one day. For example:

```
value: 28.298,
time: 21 May 2015 1:18:06 AM

value: 28.298,
time: 21 May 2015 12:15:07 PM

value: 35.046,
time: 21 May 2015 12:20:08 PM

value: 35.046,
time: 21 May 2015 12:30:15 PM

value: 23.004,
time: 22 May 2015 8:55:06 PM

value: 23.004,
time: 22 May 2015 9:45:06 PM
```

I'd to have this instead:

```
21/05 01:19:06 AM to 21/05 12:15:07 PM, value: 28.298
21/05 12:25:08 PM to 21/05 12:30:15 PM, value: 35.046
22/05 09:40:06 PM to 22/05 09:45:06 PM, value: 23.004

^---------------^    ^---------------^        ^------^
   begin time           end time                value
```

What's the best way to achieve this? What I've tried so far is to obtain all the values  every 5 minutes, and then organize the file at the end of the day. But that seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Are you using the current time ( as of the request ) as the start time? Do you not have a database available to store the values rather than using a text file?

Comment: You can just compare the value to the last value availalbe and only create new "row" line, when the value changed.

Comment: @pcnate: If the value was 23.22 from time X to time Y, then the `StartTime` would be `X` and `EndTime` would be `Y`. I can have a database, but I'd prefer to have just a text file associated with this.

Comment: I would think that using a text file is going to be unnecessarily complex, but I'll let that up to you. Personally I would probably use an array which I would json encode before writing to the file. Do you need to worry about day light savings or time adjustments?

Comment: @pcnate: Nope, DST is not a concern at all. That's the approach I've been following (see my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30464839/3993063)).

Comment: @JosephJohn I've answered previouse question